# use class properties or pass arguments

Tags: php, oop

I have doubts about using class properties or passing arguments(by value or reference) between functions in class.

I have these two sample codes:

first one use a private property `$this->_p2` to make variable accessible in functions.
second code use a variable `$p2` to pass variable between functions.

i don't need to get `$_p2` outside of class like `$object->getP2()` and it doesn't add meaning to MyClass object so defining private `_$p2` seems unnecessary but code seems cleaner to me with not passing `$p2` and using `$this->_p2`

how should i decide between class properties and passing arguments(by value or reference ) when both of them are possible options?

```
class MyClass {
      private $_p1;
      private $_p2;
      function getP1(){
        //some logic here
        $this->_p2 = '1';
        $this->d();
        if (//$this->_p2 is like)
        return ...
        else ...
      }
      function d(){
        // some logic
        $this->_p2 = $this->_p2 * 2;
        $this->e();
      }
      function e(){
        if (//some condition){
          $this->d();
      }
    }
     $object = new MyClass();
     $object->getP1();
```

---

```
class MyClass {
  private $_p1;
  function getP1(){
    //some logic here
    $p2 = '1';
    $this->d($p2);
    if (//$p2 is like)
    return ..
    else ...
  }
  function d(&$p2){
    // some logic 
    $p2 = $p2 * 2;
    $this->e($p2);
  }
  function e(&$p2){
    if (//some condition){
      $this->d($p2);
  }
}
 $object = new MyClass();
 $object->getP1();
```

Comment: Class properties are more something that the object has, so a product has a name, description, size etc.  Parameters are more temporary bits of information which a function needs to be able to do it's job.   So you need to decide what the role is of the information and store it in the relevant place.

Comment: Passing arguments here is a little ambiguous.  Properties are there for a reason.  Perhaps try reading around when to use class properties/object attributes.